# JSONCPP Writing to files after Serial Display

Tags: json

I wanted Json File's indent to be displayed in series.

[image]

However, after Json File was created, the indent was marked as follows.

[image]

Is there any way to display parallel indent in series?

Answer (score 0):

My code is this

```
Json::Value root;
Json::Value vec(Json::arrayValue);
Json::Value test1;


root["encoding"] = "UTF-8";
vec.append("python");
vec.append("c++");
vec.append("ruby");
root["indent"]["length"] = 3;
root["indent"]["use_space"] = true;

Json::StyledWriter writer;

std::string resultString=writer.write(root);
```